# ManyToMany query question

Tags: mysql, sql, django

I have three simple tables: groups, permissions and group_permissions on a ManyToMany basis.
My problem is in performing a query that, given the group id (pk), will retrive a resultset with all permissions, including the ones associated with the given group and the ones not associated with the group.

I have tried something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM permission
LEFT JOIN group_permissions ON group_permissions.permission_id = permission.id  
LEFT JOIN group ON group_permissions.group_id = group.id
WHERE group.id = 123
```

but it just dont work...

Any sugestions?

**Thank you all for the answears, i just resolved my problem in less than 30 minuts! Isn't this something?**

```
SELECT * 
FROM auth_permission
LEFT JOIN auth_group_permissions ON auth_group_permissions.permission_id = auth_permission.id AND auth_group_permissions.group_id = 123    
LEFT JOIN auth_group ON auth_group.id = auth_group_permissions.group_id
```

Comment: Is this the complete query? Where's the test for the given group id that you mention?

Comment: i forgot :( Just edited it.tk

Comment: That's what I suspected, which is why I asked the question. As I mentioned in my comment to Steve Mayne below, you cannot check that value in the where clause as it negates the left join. I've posted an answer to address this.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the various comments, you cannot test the value of group.id in the WHERE clause as it will negate the LEFT JOIN and force it to behave like an INNER JOIN.

Instead, make that test part of the JOIN condition:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM permission
        LEFT JOIN group_permissions 
            ON group_permissions.permission_id = permission.id  
        LEFT JOIN `group` 
            ON group_permissions.group_id = `group`.id
                AND `group`.id = 123
```

Comment: You've made a very good point, and now the LEFT JOIN is not negated. Still, i'm getting duplicated items (for instance, permissions associated with other groups)
I've managed to get around it like this:
    SELECT * 
    FROM permission
    LEFT JOIN group_permissions ON group_permissions.permission_id = permission.id AND group_permissions.group_id = 123  
    LEFT JOIN group ON group_permissions.group_id = group.id
    
Thanks

Comment: sorry for the formatting, just can see how to pust code in here :)

Answer (score 2):

`group` is a keyword in SQL.  It's not generally a good idea to have a table or field named using a keyword, but if you have to, then you must enclose them in the backtick character usually found in the top-left hand corner of the keyboard, under the escape key:

```
SELECT * 
FROM permission
LEFT JOIN group_permissions ON group_permissions.permission_id = permission.id  
LEFT JOIN `group` ON group_permissions.group_id = `group`.id
```

What's the group id being used to specify?  If you're not filtering using it, what does it need to be specified for?

Comment: But you don't want to check group.id = 123 in the WHERE clause, that will negate the LEFT JOIN and force it to behave like an INNER JOIN.

Comment: That's true - it's a bit confusing to be honest, as it says "retrieve all permissions" - so what's being specified?

Comment: i want to retrieve all permissions (just like a SELECT * FROM permissions), but with a distinction between the ones used by the given group and the others not used.

Comment: just edited it above. sorry ;), still as said above it will negate the LEFT JOIN.